# Is there any real statistics behind "the Pythagorean theorem of baseball"?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference

I'm reading a book about sabermetrics, specifically Mathletics by Wayne Winston, and in the first chapter he introduces a quantity that can be used to predict the win rate of teams:
$$\frac{\text{Points Scored}^2 }{\text{Points Scored}^2 + \text{Points Against}^2} \approx \text{% Games Won},$$
and he seems to hint that, halfway through the season, it can be used to predict the win rate *better* than the win rate of the first half of the season. He generalizes the formula to
$$ \frac{R^{\text{exp}}}{R^{\text{exp}} + 1}, $$ 
where $R$ is the ratio of points scored to points against. He then finds the best fit exponent to predict % of games won, for 3 sports, and finds for
$$ \text{Baseball: exp} \approx 2 ,$$
$$ \text{Football: exp} \approx 2.7, $$
$$ \text{Basketball: exp} \approx 14. $$
But I've realized you can express % of games won in terms of points scored and points against for each game $i$, specifically % of games won is exactly the fraction of games where the points scored $PS_i$, is greater than the points against $PA_i$:
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I\left (PS_i > PA_i\right ),$$
where $I$ is the indicator function.

Therefore my question is: 
$$ \frac{ \left (  \sum_{i=1}^n PS_i \right )^x  }{ \left ( \sum_{i=1}^nPS_i \right )^x  + \left ( \sum_{i = 1}^n PA_i \right )^x } \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I\left (PS_i > PA_i \right )$$

Is there an analytical way to find the MLE for $x$? Forgive me if I've made any naive mistakes, I'm mostly self-teaching myself statistics.

Answer (score 8):

The mathematical/statistical foundations for the "Pythagorean rule" was examined in Miller (2007).  This paper showed that if the number of runs scored by each team in each game follows a Weibull distribution with common shape parameter $\gamma$ but different scale parameters, then the generalised form of the Pythagorean rule (with generalised power $\gamma$) emerges as the predicted win probability.

That paper also fits the posited Weibull model to baseball data from 14 teams playing in the 2004 American League.  The results show a reasonable model fit, with $\hat{\gamma} \approx 1.74 \text{-} 1.82$ using various estimation techniques.  This suggests that the generalised Pythagorean rule may be a reasonable prediction technique for prediction wins-losses, but the power parameter should be a bit less than the squared value that appears in the book by Winston.

---

Miller, S. (2007) [A derivation of the Pythagorean won-loss formula in baseball](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09332480.2007.10722831?journalCode=ucha20). *Chance* **20(1)**, pp. 40-48.